# Can I have a LinkedHashSet of LinkedHashSets?

Tags: java

I have quite a few LinkedHashSets of different types of objects to pass from one java class to another, do I pack them in a bigger object (another linked hash set if this is possible) or do I just pass them in the normal way as parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both is possible.

If you pack the `LinkedHashSet`s into an other `LinkedHashSet` you are probably loosing type information as `LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<?>>` is the only way to collect all kinds of `LinkedHashSet`s in one place. You may also have a look into `HashMap` as normally you will at some point try to access a specfic sub-`LinkedHashSet`; using a map this is achieved with ease by defining constant lookup-keys in a common class or interface.

If there are always the same `LinkedHashSet`s to pass between classes, parameters or parameter objects are often a better solution as they provide type information. A parameter object's class could look like this

```
public class Parameters {
    private LinkedHashSet<String> namesSet = null;
    private LinkedHashSet<Locale> localesSet = null;

    public Parameters(LinkedHashSet<String> namesSet, LinkedHashSet<Locale> localesSet) {
        this.namesSet = namesSet;
        this.localesSet = localesSet;
    }

    public Parameters() {
    }

    public LinkedHashSet<String> getNamesSet() {
        return namesSet;
    }

    public void setNamesSet(LinkedHashSet<String> namesSet) {
        this.namesSet = namesSet;
    }

    public LinkedHashSet<Locale> getLocalesSet() {
        return localesSet;
    }

    public void setLocalesSet(LinkedHashSet<Locale> localesSet) {
        this.localesSet = localesSet;
    }
}
```

the advantage of parameter-objects is that they keep the method-signature short and can be passed around; just be careful when changing such objects by concurrent threads ;-).

Comment: I employed the Parameters class solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  For example:

```
LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashSet<String>>
```

Comment: but they are not all LinkedHashSet<String> - some of them are LinkedHashSet<UserItem> others are LinkedHashSet<ItemImage> and so on.

Comment: You can always use Object or another class if they have a common superclass or interface.